# print Float value as it is

Tags: java

I have read a content from a file which is in my local system.It is in float type.So while printing the output I could not get value before the decimal point.What needs to be included so that i will get an exact output.

I want the output like 1.68765 But  I am getting .68765
Also i need to append output from another file with this out.

Content of the file will be like this but without double line spaces inbetween.Next to each other but in next next line

```
1

. 

6

8

7

6

5
```

Here is my code

```
package testing;
import java.io.*;
class read {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/Movies/test.txt"));
            try {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    line = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the file too?

Comment: Also, you're skipping the first line of your file. `line = br.readLine()` in the loop should be after `sysout`

Comment: Just read in everything as string then parse it to double/float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String line = br.readLine();` had read the first line ,use

```
 String line = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

As you may see, you're skipping the first line by using the following. You're reading two lines before printing one so the first is skipped.

```
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

---

### Solution

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
float myFloat = Float.valueOf(sb.toString());
```

Assign the value of the line from the file directly in your loop test. This will save you from headaches and is way more intuitive.

Now since you already have a `StringBuilder` object, I suggest you append all the lines and then cast its value to a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the scanner class to read your input and the nextFloat class to get the next floating point number -

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:/Movies/test.txt"));
while(scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
 System.out.println(scanner.nextFloat());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicay you are skipping first line as @yassin-hajaj mentioned, you can solve this in 2 ways:

In JDK8 it would look like this:

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("D:/Movies/test.txt"));
String valueAsString = lines.collect(Collectors.joining()); // join all characters into a string
Float value = Float.valueOf(valueAsString);// parse it to a float
System.out.printf("%.10f", value); // will print vlaue with 10 digits after comma
```

Or you can do it by (JDK7+):

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try ( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/Movies/test.txt"))){ // this will close are streams after exiting this block

                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine())!=null) { // read line and assign to line variable
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had an error after editig this message:) After this fix it works as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/test.txt"));
            try {

                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the `readLine()` method within the `while` condition.

Also, `float` may not be printed the way you expect, ie, fewer digits will be displayed.

```
public class Reader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/test.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(line));
        br.close();
    }
}
```

> **Sample output:**
>
>   1.68765
>   54.4668489
>   672.9821368